# Unknown error in txtview.settext in android

Tags: android, textview

I want to set txt of an text view from a query but I get "index -1 requested with size 1 error..Can some one help me?

```
    Cursor information = db.rawQuery("select id as _id,description from poet where _id="+Peot_ID_for_db,null);
    TextView poet_info=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Poet_info);
    poet_info.setText(information.getString(information.getColumnIndex("_id")));
//  poet_info.append(information.getString(information.getColumnIndex("description")));
```

I searched this error but nothing found in google..I hope you can help me..
I have just one row in my table that matches with this query so I think I dint need any loop or sth like that to get all rows

Comment: [Here is a great little SQLite tutorial that I used when I started](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you start off by using a moveTo function.

It will not get a row for you until you do.

Example:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToNext()

Snippet:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

while(information.moveToNext()) {
    sb.append(information.getString(information.getColumnIndex("_id"))+" ");
}

poet_info.setText(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 4):

You haven't move the cursor to the row..It will throw that error for you

Try using this

```
if(information.moveToFirst())
{
do{


//Write your code here
}
while(information.moveToNext())

}
```

Comment: In this instance `information.moveToFirst()` and `information.moveToNext()`